# Structure and Vibrational Spectroscopy

Tags: physical-chemistry, symmetry

What are the irreducible representations of the C-O stretching modes in free CO, $\ce{[Fe(CO)5][Fe(CO)4]^2-}$?

I think Free CO irreducible representation is A2.

For $\ce{[Fe(CO)5]}$ irreducible representation is 2A1'+E'+A2'' but I am really not sure about $\ce{[Fe(CO)4]^2-}$.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: You skipped a lot of steps - how did you derive the irreps for Fe(CO)5? Exactly what problems are you facing in applying the same steps to Fe(CO)4(2-)?